# Listview on android, scroll only with scrollbar

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

Is it possible in Android to create a `Listview` and on the right a custom scrollbar so that the scroll for the `ListView` would only work if someone presses on the scrollbar area?

So if a person clicks on the first 70% of the width it would select an item in the `ListView`, but if they clicked on the right 30% there would be a scrollbar and it would not select any items in the `ListView`, but would only scroll the `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

I think a normal listview should be able to do that a.

Comment: How can a normal listview do that? On a normal one it always scrolls on all area, doesn't matter where you click

Comment: is that matter? if you want to select item in list, then you can just include button.setOnItemClickListner(new OnItemClickListener) to add what should you do after select the item

Comment: otherwise, if there is no any code there how would it select the item in listview.